# RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.OperationInterruptedException

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange

I'm working on my student project related to Notification Brokers. As a sample our teacher provided us with the following repository: https://github.com/DeveloperStories/RabbitMQ.

I selected `Publisher` project inside the `RabbitMQ` solution and ran it without changing any bit of code.

Unfortunately, I received the following error:

[image]

As I investigate further, all of projects throw the error at the line `using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())`.

What's interesting, none of my classmates faced any similar issue.

I downloaded the Erlang language.
I allowed `5672` and `15672` ports in my Windows firewall (as was requested). The http://localhost:15672/ page works just fine. What can it be?

Comment: Be sure that you are not using Erlang26.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was related to the newest version of the Erlang language (26.0), which was not supported by RabbitMQ.

The solution was to install an earlier version instead (25.0 in my case).